# Как сделать однострочный калькулятор?

Tags: java

Каким образом сделать этот калькулятор однострочным

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class HelloWorld {
    public static void main(String[] agrs){

        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        int a = in.nextInt();

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        String U = sc.nextLine();

        Scanner lo = new Scanner(System.in);
        int b = lo.nextInt();



        sc.close();

        if (U.equals("+")) {
            System.out.print(a+b);
            }
            else if (U.equals("-")) {
            System.out.print(a-b);
            }
            else if (U.equals("*")) {
            System.out.print(a*b);
            }
            else if (U.equals("/"))
                {
            System.out.print(a/b);}

        }

    }
```

Comment: Нафига тебе 3 scanner'а?

Comment: И что значит однострочным?

Comment: вы имеете ввиду чтоб можно было целиком пример в одну строку написать?

Comment: Да, целиком в одну строку

Comment: примеры простые в одно действие или сложные, где надо учитывать порядок вычисления?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Забираешь строку целиком со сканера. Если примеры простые, то парсишь ее, чтоб понять какие числа и какая операция и считаешь. Если примеры сложные где надо учитывать порядок вычисления, то используй метод обратной польской записи, алгоритм можно посмотреть здесь http://www.interface.ru/home.asp?artid=1492

Максимально просто в лоб

```
 public static void main(String[]args){

    Scanner in = new Scanner( System.in);
    String str = in.next();

    Double result = null;
    String[] numbers;

    if(str.indexOf( '+' )>0){
        numbers = str.split( "[+]" );
        result = Double.parseDouble( numbers[0] ) + Double.parseDouble( numbers[1] );
    }else if(str.indexOf( '-' )>0){
        numbers = str.split( "[-]" );
        result = Double.parseDouble( numbers[0] ) - Double.parseDouble( numbers[1] );
    }else if(str.indexOf( '/' )>0){
        numbers = str.split( "[/]" );
        result = Double.parseDouble( numbers[0] ) / Double.parseDouble( numbers[1] );
    }else if(str.indexOf( '*' )>0){
        numbers = str.split( "[*]" );
        result = Double.parseDouble( numbers[0] ) * Double.parseDouble( numbers[1] );
    }else{

    }

    System.out.println(result);

}
```

здесь не учтены обработка ошибок ввода, обработка исключений и т.д. это вам надо доработать

Comment: Максимально простые

Comment: Огромное спасибо

Answer (score 1):

выражение в 1 ну строку пример 25+5 или что Вы имели ввиду ?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Calculator {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Calculator ready enter expression:\n enter 'exit' for leave");
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int a = 0;
        int b = 0;
        String op = "";
        do {
            String input = sc.next();
            if (input.equals("exit")) {
                break;
            }
            String[] strings = input.split("\\W");
            String[] operator = input.split("\\w");
            try {
                a = Integer.parseInt(strings[0]);
                b = Integer.parseInt(strings[1]);
                op = operator[operator.length - 1];
                System.out.println("Result = " + operation(a, b, op));
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("Error input try again");
            }
        } while (true);
    }

    private static int operation(int a, int b, String op) {
        switch (op) {
            case "*":
                return a * b;
            case "+":
                return a + b;
            case "-":
                return a - b;
            case "/":
                return a / b;
            default:
                return 0;
        }
    }
}
```